# use array of pthread conditional variable inside a struct

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to create pthread example which will create pthread conditional and pthread mutex inside a struct and then i will use that conditional and mutex variable inside a fucntion.

My source is:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct SubObj {
  //pthread_mutex_t *mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
  //pthread_cond_t *cond = (pthread_cond_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_cond_t));
  pthread_cond_t *cond;
  pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
} subobj;

const size_t NUMTHREADS = 4;

int done = 0;

void* ThreadEntry(void* id) 
{
  const int myid = (long) id;
  const int workloops = 200;

  printf("[thread %d] done is now %d. Signalling cond.\n", myid, done);

  for (int i = 0; i < workloops; i++) 
  {
      printf("[thread %d] working (%d/%d)\n", myid, i, workloops);
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(&subobj.mutex);
  done++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&subobj.mutex);
  pthread_cond_signal(&subobj.cond);

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  subobj.mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
  subobj.cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

  pthread_t threads[NUMTHREADS];

  for (int t = 0; t < NUMTHREADS; t++)
      pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, ThreadEntry, (void*) (long) t);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&subobj.mutex);

  while (done < NUMTHREADS) 
  {
      printf("[thread main] done is %d which is < %d so waiting on cond\n",
            done, (int) NUMTHREADS);

      pthread_cond_wait(&subobj.cond, &subobj.mutex);
  }

  printf("[thread main] done == %d so everyone is done\n", (int) NUMTHREADS);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&subobj.mutex);

  return 0;
}
```

But after compiling this source, it gives me error. Really passing some bad time on this.

```
[ Compiling source file (condInStruct.c) to bitcode 
(../obj/condInStruct.c.prof.bc) ]
condInStruct.c:49:17: error: expected expression
    subobj.mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
                   ^
/usr/include/pthread.h:87:3: note: expanded from macro ' 

 PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER'
  { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, __PTHREAD_SPINS, { 0, 0 } } }
  ^
 condInStruct.c:50:16: error: expected expression
    subobj.cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
                  ^
/usr/include/pthread.h:186:34: note: expanded from macro 
'PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER'
#define PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (void *) 0, 0, 0 } }
```

What is the best approach to create pthead sync objects array inside struct and then use this in the fucntions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for pointing this. i have removed that duplicate and  now posting the errors.

Comment: ahhh ... my bad ... sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can not use this macro for assignment (in a function body). You should use:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&subobj.mutex, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&subobj.cond, NULL);
```

instead. Let's investigate why, by looking at preprocessor output:

```
subobj.mutex = 
# 39 "main.c" 3 4
            { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, { 0, 0 } } }
```

It's the preprocessed output of line:

```
 subobj.mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

That kind of assignment is allowed only during declaration.

Complete code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct SubObj {
  //pthread_mutex_t *mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
  //pthread_cond_t *cond = (pthread_cond_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_cond_t));
  pthread_cond_t cond;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} subobj;

const size_t NUMTHREADS = 4;

int done = 0;

void* ThreadEntry(void* id) 
{
  const int myid = (long) id;
  const int workloops = 200;

  printf("[thread %d] done is now %d. Signalling cond.\n", myid, done);

  for (int i = 0; i < workloops; i++) 
  {
      printf("[thread %d] working (%d/%d)\n", myid, i, workloops);
  }

  pthread_mutex_lock(&subobj.mutex);
  done++;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&subobj.mutex);
  pthread_cond_signal(&subobj.cond);

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  pthread_mutex_init(&subobj.mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&subobj.cond, NULL);
  pthread_t threads[NUMTHREADS];

  for (int t = 0; t < NUMTHREADS; t++)
      pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, ThreadEntry, (void*) (long) t);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&subobj.mutex);

  while (done < NUMTHREADS) 
  {
      printf("[thread main] done is %d which is < %d so waiting on cond\n",
            done, (int) NUMTHREADS);

      pthread_cond_wait(&subobj.cond, &subobj.mutex);
  }

  printf("[thread main] done == %d so everyone is done\n", (int) NUMTHREADS);

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&subobj.mutex);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually now segfault happens. i just use only the first two line of ur example in the main function.

Comment: Because you edited struct to use pointers. In my version I removed pointers.

Comment: Replace  `pthread_cond_t *cond` with `pthread_cond_t cond` , similar for `mutex` field.

Comment: still the segfault happens for me. Is the example working properly for u?

Comment: Added the entire code. I compile with `gcc -o main main.c -pthread -std=c11`

Comment: @EricIpsum for the love of god, turn up you warning levels. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` added to your build command. The plethora of issues should be loud and clear. There are a host of incompatible pointer warnings, most of them because you're passing addresses of pointers rather than addresses of concrete structures to various pthread apis.

Comment: @pbn i found the root cause of the problem . The segfault only happens on my tool which i am using to compile. from command line it works.